# How to smooth a curve with large noise which is only in certain part?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, smoothing, data-processing

I'd like to smooth a scatter plot shown below (the points are very dense), and the data is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M7ayjUFF1JZ6KjepqcCS1L7twggo2ip3/view?usp=sharing).

[image]

There is large noise in the middle of the curve, and I'd like to smooth the curve, also the y value should **monotonically increase**.

Since there are lots of curves like this, it is kind of hard to know where the noise is in the curve.

I tried `scipy.signal.savgol_filter`, but it didn't work.

The code I used is:

```
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = np.loadtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',')
x = s[:, 0]
y = s[:, 1]
yhat = savgol_filter(y, 551, 3)

plt.plot(x, y, 'r')
plt.plot(x, yhat, 'b')
plt.show()
```

Suggestions are really appreciated. Thanks!

***-------------------update-------------------------***

Following Colin's method, I get the results I want. Here is the code:

```
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = np.loadtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',')
x = s[:, 0]
y = s[:, 1]
yhat = savgol_filter(y, 551, 3)

tolerance = 0.2
increased_span = 150
filter_size = 11

first_pass = medfilt(y,filter_size)
diff = (y-first_pass)**2
first = np.argmax(diff>tolerance) - increased_span
last = len(y) - np.argmax(diff[::-1]>tolerance) + increased_span
print (first, last)
#interpolate between increased span
yhat[first:last] = np.interp(x[first:last], [x[first], x[last]],  [y[first], y[last]])


f = interpolate.interp1d(x, yhat, kind='slinear')
x_inter = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 1000)
y_inter = f(x_inter)
y_inter = savgol_filter(y_inter, 41, 3)

plt.plot(x, y, 'r')
plt.plot(x, yhat, 'b')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we firstly isolate the trouble area there are many ways to remove it.  Here is an example:

```
tolerance = 0.2
increased_span = 150
filter_size = 11

#find noise
first_pass = medfilt(y,filter_size)
diff = (yhat-first_pass)**2
first = np.argmax(diff>tolerance) - increased_span
last = len(y) - np.argmax(diff[::-1]>tolerance) + increased_span

#interpolate between increased span
yhat[first:last] = np.interp(x[first:last], [x[first], x[last]],  [y[first], y[last]])
```

[image]

Comment: where do the parameters come from? I have a forecast that sometimes, particularly when it is not doing so good really, produces a line that is a lot noisier than the observed trendline. it would be great to be able to automate the correction